# Official MongoDB Source Connector for Apache Kafka with MongoDB-4.0

Tags: mongodb, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, mongodb-kafka-connector

I have a requirement where I have to capture MongoDB ChangeStream (inserts/updates etc) events and take some actions (save to OracleDB).
I have thought of this design which seems to be good:

`"MongoDB-ChangeStream" --> "MongoDB Source Connector for Apache Kafka" --> "Kafka Broker-Topic" --> "Java Service" --> OracleDB`

**My question here is, I am using MongoDB-4.0 and "MongoDB Source Connector for Apache Kafka" was introduced in MongoDB-4.2. Can I still use "MongoDB Source Connector for Apache Kafka" with MongoDB-4.0?**

MongoDB Source Connector for Apache Kafka - Official page:
https://www.confluent.io/hub/mongodb/kafka-connect-mongodb

Official page of "MongoDB Source Connector for Apache Kafka" does not talk about any prerequisite in terms of the version of MongoDB.

**My second question, can this(MongoDB Source Connector for Apache Kafka) set up be done on Windows?**

Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### A working solution for MongoDB(4.0) ChangeStreams with Official MongoDB Connector (mongodb-kafka-connect-mongodb-1.1.0) for Apache Kafka without using Confluent Hub Client

1. Download Official MongoDB Kafka Connector:
   `i. open https://www.confluent.io/hub/
   ii. search "mongodb"
   iii. select from dropdown "MongoDB Connector for Apache Kafka"
   iv. Click on Download in Download installtion (note I am not using Confluent)
   v. unzip the downloaded file (on windows)
       eg. F:\software\mongodb\mongodb-kafka-connect-mongodb-1.1.0
   vi. inside "etc" folder open file "MongoSourceConnector.properties"
   vii. Make only one change with respect to MongoDB url:
       connection.uri=mongodb://localhost:27017,localhost:27018
   viii. One change in Kafka:
       In F:\software\kafka_2.12-2.4.1\config\connect-standalone.properties:
       plugin.path=F:\\software\\mongodb\\mongodb-kafka-connect-mongodb-1.1.0`
2. start Zookeeper: 
   `bin/zookeeper-server-start.sh config/zookeeper.properties`
3. start Kafka:
   `.\bin\windows\kafka-server-start.bat .\config\server.properties`
4. start Kafka-Connect:
   `bin\windows\connect-standalone.bat config\connect-standalone.properties F:\software\mongodb\mongodb-kafka-connect-mongodb-1.1.0\etc\MongoSourceConnector.properties`
5. Add new Document to MongoDB Collection and you should have a new topic created dbName.collectionName and ChangeStream event should appear on this topic.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is already in the [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/kafka-connector/master/kafka-compatibility/):

> The Kafka Source Connector requires MongoDB 3.6 or later as your data
>   source if you are using change streams with a collection only. If you
>   need to watch a database or deployment, you need MongoDB 4.0 or later.

---

Regarding your second question; Yes, it is possible to run Kafka on Windows.

Comment: Thanks Giorgos for the answer. Your answer motivated me enough to finally make it work. :-)
Thanks a lot.